# Vercel/Next.js Redirects - Underscores to Hypens

Tags: next.js, vercel

On Vercel, I have a Next.js app router with a statically exported website where I need to redirect all URLs containing underscores (`_`) to hyphens (`-`). For instance, I have `/british_columbia/fanny_bay`, and I need it to be `/british-columbia/fanny-bay` due to backlinks to the website.

What can I add to `vercel.json` to convert all URLs with underscores (`_`) to hyphens (`-`)?

```json
{
  "trailingSlash": false,
  "cleanUrls": true
  "redirects": [
    {
      "source": "find underscores",
      "destination": "change to hyphens",
      "permanent": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can achieve this by changing the `next.config` in next 13+  just check the rewrite section in next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites)